# what is the most efficient way to add an eventlistener on a large number of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, event-handling

So, here is what I am wondering about.
I have a code snippet like the one I attached.

This code runs just fine, what I am doing here is getting all the html elements with a class selector, and binding a predefined function on those elements click event.

My question is, when I have a thousands of elements, or even more. should I just run a loop like this and assign the function or is there any better or more efficient way to do this with pure JavaScript ?

If this is the most efficient one, and there is none other, or there are other ways, some references or explanation would really helpful, I found no relevant information anywhere else.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('element');

var printNumbers = function() {
  this.innerHTML = this.dataset.position;
}

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", printNumbers);
}
```

```css
.element {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #cecece;
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" data-position="1"></div>
<div class="element" data-position="2"></div>
<div class="element" data-position="3"></div>
<div class="element" data-position="4"></div>

<!-- more elements here with continious data-position attribute -->

<div class="element" data-position="1000"></div>
```

Comment: You can assign a single listener to the parent and track the `target` property of the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the click handler on a parent, since events bubble upwards you can catch them from the parent and handle them there, update snippet:

```js
var printNumbers = function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('element')) {
    event.target.innerHTML = event.target.dataset.position;
  }
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', printNumbers)
```

```css
.element {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #cecece;
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" data-position="1"></div>
<div class="element" data-position="2"></div>
<div class="element" data-position="3"></div>
<div class="element" data-position="4"></div>

<!-- more elements here with continious data-position attribute -->

<div class="element" data-position="1000"></div>
```

Comment: You need to check the parents of the event target too - if there's a child in these divs, when it's clicked, the passed target property will be the child and not the `.element` div.

Comment: Thanks kfedorov91 and @Al.G. , I will do some study on this and check if this actually helps me in my scenario. Will accept this as answer in no time then